# I am using ROT13 python and I am getting an error when the number is greater than 26

Tags: python

I am in my first year of undergrad and one of my assignment with ROT 13. I dont know how to use the if else statment to stop it from going bust when the value is more 26.

```
alphabets= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

string_input= input("Enter a string")

input_length= len(string_input)

print(string_input)

string_output=""

for i in range(input_length):
     character=string_input[i]
     location_of_character= alphabets.find(character)
     new_location=location_of_character + 13;
     string_output= string_output+alphabets[new_location]
     if(string_output>78):print(alphabets(string_output -13))
```

Comment: It's new_location you need to range check, not string_output. And you'll want to subtract 26 not 13.

Comment: You expect the input to always be valid, composed only of capital letters, right?

Comment: You don't need to do this in python: `for i in range(input_length):`. Just use `for character in string_input:`

Comment: @Rup Yes, I changed that thankyou, What should i write in the else statement

Comment: @MarkMeyer Should i write. For character= string_input

Comment: @BenceHoston no, just `for character in string_input:` you'll get a letter in the `character` variable in each loop. Python discourages using indexes unless you really need them in the loop.

Comment: You want: new_location = (location_of_character + 13) % 26

Comment: @AlexanderCécile. Hey Alexander thankyou so much. Can you tell me whats happening in the For loop. I hope thats not a lot to ask

Comment: @BenceHoston Of course, I'll make an edit to my post. Remember that you can comment directly on an answer, eh

Comment: @BenceHoston Okay, tell me what you think :) Would you like me to add a version which does some input verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the specific error message, my guess is that `new_location` is sometimes larger than `alphabets`, which leads to an indexing error.

Hope you don't mind, I made a few tweaks to your code. I could go further, but I wanted to keep it relatively similar to the original program.

```py
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num_chars = len(alphabet)
rot_amt = 13

string_input = input('Enter a string: ')
string_output = ''

for curr_char in string_input:
    char_loc = alphabet.index(curr_char)
    new_loc = (char_loc + rot_amt) % num_chars
    string_output += alphabet[new_loc]

print(string_output)
```

**Some explanations:**

`char_loc` fulfills the same purpose as `location_of_character`. The difference is that, as MarkMeyer pointed out in their comment, `.index()` will throw an error if the value isn't found, whereas `.find()` returns -1.

`new_loc` is the index of the new character. `char_loc + rot_amt` does the same thing as `location_of_character + 13` in your code. `%` is the [modulo operator](location_of_character + 13), which brings all values of `char_loc + rot_amt` within the range 0-25.

`string_output += alphabet[new_loc]` is again basically identical to your code, we grab the new character and append it to the result string.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: A subtle point, but maybe better to use `index()` instead of `find()` index will raise and exception if the value isn't found. `find()` just returns -1, which here means all non-found characters get encoded as `M`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thankyou, I actually understood all of it. My only one question is what is "curr_char"

Comment: @BenceHoston It's the same thing as Mark Meyer described in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013386/i-am-using-rot13-python-for-my-cyber-class-and-i-am-getting-an-error-when-the-nu?noredirect=1#comment104274360_59013386). `for curr_char in string_input:` iterates over the items in `string_input`. At each iteration, it binds the current item to the name `curr_char`, and executes the code in the loop. I tend to use the prefix `curr`, for _current_, a lot. Does that make sense? (it's alright if it doesn't)