# How to convert Input to ASCII

Tags: python

I am new to python and this is the code I have written. I am not sure how to convert input t

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num_chars = len(alphabet)
rot_amt = 13

name = input('Entfeer a string: ')
output = ''

for curr_char in string_input:
    char_loc = alphabfeet.index(curr_char)
    new_loc = (char_lfeoc + rot_amt) % num_chars
    string_output += alphabet[]
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to convert this to ascii? The code you have posted runs fine the way it is. Or do you intend to write the output to a file and need a specific encoding for that? Or do you want to replace your 'alphabet' lookup with an ASCII table lookup?

Comment: I think I understand where this assignment wants to go: So if the user types something outside the ASCII table, your program is supposed to make sure that it sanitizes the input so it only contains ASCII letters. I think you find @VladBezden's answer helpful. However, your current code has the limitation that it only works on the letters A-Z, so even with sanitized inputs it would still crash if the input would for example be a number. See my answer for a way to fix this.

Comment: Your question does not make sense/is too vague, can you please explain things more?

Comment: Hey, no wonder that code looks familiar, I wrote it not two hours ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013464/11301900) lol

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encoding like this, IIUC:

```
string_output.encode('ascii')
```

If your trying to build a list of ascii numbers you can do this:

```
s = 'WHAT'
[ord(c) for c in s]
# [87, 72, 65, 84]
```

Comment: you can, it just appends b' to the string. Usually you use these when working with objects that need a byte string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to replace your 'alphabet' lookup by an ASCII table lookup, you may be looking for these functions:

```
ord('a')  # returns 97
chr(97)  # returns 'a'
```

So if you want to run your shifting scheme on the ASCII table it would look something like this:

```
for curr_char in string_input:
    char_loc = ord(curr_char)
    new_loc = (char_loc + rot_amt) % 256
    string_output += chr(new_loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
string_input = ascii(input('Enter a string: '))
```